# Exception when connecting to Shopify

Tags: exception, curl, shopify

I have developed a Shopify app
When calling the shop.json in shopify it sometimes throws a ShopifyCurlException for a specific client : Couldn't resolve host 'https:'
For 99% of the users this never happens.
Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

> Couldn't resolve host 'https:'

Curl return more or less the same errors from the command line:

```
$ curl https://thisisnotadomain   
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: thisisnotadomain

$ curl https://                  
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: https
```

It look like curl is unable to resolve the domain from the URL you've pass, most likely because you've pass "https://".